# How to use variable in import statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, jinja2

I am using some 3rd party JS file which uses an import statement inside the JS file itself. I am using Django, and that css file is in `STATICFILES_DIRS`, which I can access through `{% static 'css/main.css' %}`. This is the file being imported.

In js this is being imported something like this

`import '../../css/main.css'`

I have declared a variable in index.html that holds this value

index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    const main_css = "{% static 'css/main.css' %}"
</script>
```

In my main.js file I am using this syntax

```
@import `${main_css}`
```

which doesn't work, the DOM doesn't change. Any tips?

Comment: You can't import a javascript file directly in javascript, ECMAScript only supports module importing. @import statements work when you pre-process your files with webpack or bower or something similar.